# The name of element in the #process callback (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi

I'm trying to create a new form element representing the bbcode editor, which is a compound object of the toolbar and native textarea element.
So my hook_element_info() looks like:

```
function bbeditor_element_info() {
    $type['bbeditor'] = array(
        '#input' => TRUE,
        '#cols' => 60,
        '#rows' => 5,
        '#resizable' => TRUE,
        '#process' => array('process_bbeditor'),
        '#theme_wrappers' => array('bbeditor', 'form_element'),
    );
    return $type;
}
```

But how do I get the name of element in the process function to passthrough it into the nested textarea element?

```
function process_bbeditor($element, &$form_state) {
    ...
    // Insert the textarea element as a child.
    $name = 'textarea'; // <------------- How do I get the name?
    $element[$name] = $textarea;
    return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$form_state variable store the information of form's state (means you can use this variable to get the value of form element)

Like :

```
$form_state['element_name']['value'];
```

This will give you the value for form element. i'm not very sure that $form_state['element_name'] will give you the name of the element or it may return array.

Please check by using

```
var_dump($form_state['element_name']);
```

in your hook what it print

```
function process_bbeditor($element, &$form_state) {
    ...

    var_dump($form_state['element_name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, being aware that this may be a bit late for the OP, I just want to add an answer for the benefit of those that may stumble upon this  :)

Assuming you are on a drupal 7 installation:

```
$element['#name']
```

contains the name of the element, provided it has a name. It will automatically receive a name if rendered via drupal_get_form, in which case it receives the name of the corresponding array element in the initial form array. It is also possible to set the `#name`  attribute directly, e.g.

```
$form['bbeditor_test'] = array(
  '#type' => 'bbeditor',
  '#name' => 'use-this-name',
  // some more stuff ....
);
```

It often makes sense to re-use a `_process` callback for custom fields defined for Drupal's field API (i.e. when defining fields via [hook_field_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7) and related hooks). In such scenarios note, that the name of the element is not contained in the `#name` attribute but in the `#field_name` attribute.

So, assuming `process_bbeditor` is also used for the field API fields we would have something like:

```
function process_bbeditor($element, &$form_state,$form) {
  // some stuff ...
  $element_name = ''; 
  if (isset($element['#name'])) {
    $element_name = $element['#name'];
  }
  elseif (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    $element_name = $element['#field_name'];
  }
  else {  // to handle the rare case when drupal_render is called directly on the parent array and #name isn't set
    $element_name = 'undefined';
  }
  // some more stuff using $element_name ....
  return $element;
}
```